# Date code not converting to correct date format

Tags: php, date, date-formatting

I am confused as to why my date is getting converted to unix default before entry into mysql. I am sure the code is correct but cannot see why this is not working. It should convert the date that I post to script.

I would be grateful if someone could check the code and point out my error. Many thanks.

> Post: 22/08/2017 05:03:29 Output:1970-01-01 12:00:00

```
$date = $_POST['datetimepicker'];
$parsedDate = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime($date));
```

Comment: If the input date comes from a JavaScript date picker you better configure it to format the date in the desired format (`Y-m-d H:i:s`) when it puts the value in the form.

Answer (score 2):

`d/m/Y` is not one of the [date formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) recognized by the PHP date parser.
Given the number of digits in the date components, the parser assumes `m/d/Y` and because `22` is not a valid month number it fails and `strtotime()` returns `0`.

You can use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to tell the parser what format do you use:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', '22/08/2017 05:03:29');
echo($date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

# 2017-08-22 05:03:29
```

Comment: This code causes this error: <b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct() [&lt;a href
='datetime.--construct'&gt;datetime.--construct&lt;/a&gt;]: Failed to parse time string (22/08/2017 05
:03:29) at position 0 (2): Unexpected character' Thanks

Comment: `22/08/2017 05 :03:29` There is a unwanted space in your time

Comment: It works well as long as the provided input uses the format: https://3v4l.org/KQQZW

Comment: Not usre if it makes any difference but i am using php 5.3

Comment: [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) is available since PHP 5.3, it should work without problems.

Comment: @axiac not sure what you mean by this line: 'It works well as long as the provided input uses the format' thanks

Comment: The date in your first comment is `22/08/2017 05 :03:29`. It contains a space (after `05`) that should not be there. Of course it cannot be parsed. The format specified by the first argument is `d/m/Y H:i:s`. The parser allows one space in the format (between date and time ) match multiple consecutive spaces in the input date but the other pieces must match exactly.

Comment: Where is that space coming from. It is not in the post? Thanks